Contradictory instructions to set up IAM Identity Center trusted access
I'm just trying to set up a new organization on AWS and I was setting up IAM Identity Center. I enabled it, but the console wouldn't show up, only a message telling that it doesn't have trusted access:

It tells me to enable this setting on the AWS Organizations' services, but then, when I get there, it tells me this is unadvised and to do it from the very page I came from:

This seems like a stern warning, since I have to remove several safeguards (tick a checkbox, write a confirmation on an text box) to do it.
What should I do? I've seen other answers telling to just enable it on the AWS Organizations' services, but I'd like some confirmation that this is okay, even though so many warnings try to detract you from doing it. I can't follow the instructions the AWS consoles give me or else i'd end up stuck on an infinite loop.

I have the identical issue, which I know is not a helpful response. I asked the question on re:Post, have yet to hear anything. Did you make any progress with the issue?

I just went with it! Enabled from there despite the warnings, since docs seem to suggest it. I also re-interpreted the warning, and the text-box confirmation as being related to the dangers of enabling trusted access, and not to the fact that it was done from the Organizations page.

Excellent -- thanks for letting me know!
